# xsend.py Как авторизоваться?

Tags: python, xmpp

Есть такой скриптик для отправки сообщений по jabber. Тут его документация - http://xmpppy.sourceforge.net/basic.html Как авторизоваться? Где вписать свои логин/пароль. Нужно ли указывать сервер jabber.ru ??? Вписывал сюда:

```
for mandatory in ['jid','password']:
```

Не проходит((( Подскажите.

Вот его код:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# $Id: xsend.py,v 1.8 2006/10/06 12:30:42 normanr Exp $
import sys,os,xmpp,time

if len(sys.argv) < 2:
    print "Syntax: xsend JID text"
    sys.exit(0)

tojid=sys.argv[1]
text=' '.join(sys.argv[2:])

jidparams={}
if os.access(os.environ['HOME']+'/.xsend',os.R_OK):
    for ln in open(os.environ['HOME']+'/.xsend').readlines():
        if not ln[0] in ('#',';'):
            key,val=ln.strip().split('=',1)
            jidparams[key.lower()]=val
for mandatory in ['jid','password']:
    if mandatory not in jidparams.keys():
        open(os.environ['HOME']+'/.xsend','w').write('#Uncomment fields before use and type in correct credentials.\n#JID=romeo@montague.net/resource (/resource is optional)\n#PASSWORD=juliet\n')
        print 'Please point ~/.xsend config file to valid JID for sending messages.'
        sys.exit(0)

jid=xmpp.protocol.JID(jidparams['jid'])
cl=xmpp.Client(jid.getDomain(),debug=[])

con=cl.connect()
if not con:
    print 'could not connect!'
    sys.exit()
print 'connected with',con
auth=cl.auth(jid.getNode(),jidparams['password'],resource=jid.getResource())
if not auth:
    print 'could not authenticate!'
    sys.exit()
print 'authenticated using',auth

#cl.SendInitPresence(requestRoster=0)   # you may need to uncomment this for old server
id=cl.send(xmpp.protocol.Message(tojid,text))
print 'sent message with id',id

time.sleep(1)   # some older servers will not send the message if you disconnect immediately after sending

#cl.disconnect()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
def client(jid, password, resource):
    username, server = jid.split("@")
    cl = xmpp.Client(server, 5222, [])
    cl.connect((server, port), secure=0, use_srv = True)
    if cl.auth(username, password, resource):
        print "Auth ok!"
```

Также следовало бы поглядеть сюда: http://fateful-engine.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/
Не смотрите на количество ревизий — был сделан reset репозитория.

Answer (score -1):

```
JID=romeo@montague.net/resource (/resource is optional)\n#PASSWORD=juliet\n'
```